# Logarithmic vs Nth root transformation of Image

Tags: image-processing

This is an image for the explanation of Logarithmic Transformation of an Image. I want to ask considering a input pixel value r<sub>k</sub>, Value of n<sup>th</sup> root of r<sub>k</sub> should be greater than corresponding value of log(r<sub>k</sub>). But this image is not accordance with that?

[image: Log Transformations]

Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematicaly, inverse logarithm (or exponential) should indeed grow faster than powers, and logarithm is slower than roots... at infinity. Here, their range is limited to finite interval, so with proper scaling, you may observe such behaviors. I will come back later with numerical examples.

Comment: Here the range is limited to [0,255] and I have tried values from the range, still nth root should be greater than log

Comment: I got a hint, It might be related to double value of r ranging from [0,1], may be...here the log function is s = clog(1+r)

Comment: Indeed. Plus, scaled powers $\frac{y^\lambda-1}{\lambda}$ tend to $\log$ as $\lambda\to 0$, hence the hierarchy $x, x^{1/n},\log$